# Grails - avoiding conversion when rendering variable value in GSP

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I'm porting an older grails application to the new version (2.3.7), and I'm getting an error I don't know how to fix... Anyone here got any ideas?

On one of the webpages, I have a semi-large javascript calculating amounts. The site is multi-language, so the calculation and formatting of the amount is country-dependant. The code looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

  ... a lot of other javascript

// format an amount to display - country dependant

function formatAmount (amount) {
${country.javaScriptAmount}
}

  ... a lot of other javascript

//-->
</script>
```

The code for formatting amounts is in the per-country-constants variable "country" - it's a constant string (and declared "final"). In the old grails-version this worked fine, and the rendered page look like this:

```
// format an amount to display - country dependant

function formatAmount (amount) {

  ... other code

  var krString
  if (kkr > 0)
    if (kronor < 10)
      krString = kkr + " 00" + kronor
    else if (kronor < 100)
      krString = kkr + " 0" + kronor
    else
      krString = kkr + " " + kronor
    else
      krString = kronor.toString ()

  ... other code

}
```

But in the new version it looks like this:

```
function formatAmount (amount) {

  ... other code

  var krString
  if (kkr &gt; 0)
    if (kronor &lt; 10)
      krString = kkr + &quot; 00&quot; + kronor
    else if (kronor &lt; 100)
      krString = kkr + &quot; 0&quot; + kronor
    else
      krString = kkr + &quot; &quot; + kronor
    else
      krString = kronor.toString ()

  ... other code

}
```

How can I stop grails from converteing /" to >/</" when rendering the value of a variable in the GSP-file? I'd be most grateful for some advice! :-)

Anders from Sweden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent [Cross Site Scripting](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/guide/security.html#xssPrevention) grails escapes all content in `${}` expressions.

You could force grails to stop encoding your expressions by using the `raw` codec like this:

```
${raw(country.javaScriptAmount)}
```

or

```
<g:encodeAs codec="Raw">
    ${country.javaScriptAmount}
</g:encodeAs>
```

or

```
${country.javaScriptAmount.encodeAsRaw()}
```

Comment: Aha. Worked fine. And interesting to read about the Cross Site Scripting attack. So I guess the new default encoding is a good thing. Great that it is easy to turn of in a special case like this. Thanks for your time, both of you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

there is a config variable to control the default encoding on all GSP pages:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "none" // none, html, base64
```